# Remove array ref from array of hashes

Tags: perl

I have multi level array of hashes i want to make it single array of hashes.But i am not able to do that .

**Actual Array**

```
[
  [
    { 'country' => 'India' },
    { 'country' => 'India' }
  ],
  [
    { 'country' => 'India' },
    { 'country' => 'India' }
  ],
  [
    { 'country' => 'India' },
    { 'country' => 'India' }
  ]
];
```

**Need Array**

```
[
  { 'country' => 'India' },
  { 'country' => 'India' },
  { 'country' => 'India' },
  { 'country' => 'India' },
  { 'country' => 'India' },
  { 'country' => 'India' }
];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to dereference every sub-array and flatten it into a list of hashref elements,

```perl
my $a1 = [
    [ { country => "India" }, { country => "India" } ],
    [ { country => "India" }, { country => "India" } ],
    [ { country => "India" }, { country => "India" } ],
];

# Flatten the AoA
my $a2 = [ map @$_, @$a1 ];

use Data::Dump;
dd $a2;
```

Outputs:

```perl
[
  { country => "India" },
  { country => "India" },
  { country => "India" },
  { country => "India" },
  { country => "India" },
  { country => "India" },
]
```

Comment: @Miller I guess you don't like Dumper module? :)

Comment: Heh, [`Data::Dumper`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Data/Dumper.html) is a perfectly serviceable module.  I use it all the time too.  However, it's [default settings](http://perldoc.perl.org/Data/Dumper.html#Configuration-Variables-or-Methods) are what suck.  [`Data::Dump`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Dump) does a much better job of displaying data structures in the format that I'd prefer by default.  So yeah, I like to use the latter for output when it improves the quality of an answer.

Comment: @Miller can you mimic above output with Dumper? Yes, defaults are most probably old as module itself.

Comment: At minimum, the following defaults should be altered: `local $Data::Dumper::Purity = 1; local $Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1; local $Data::Dumper::Terse = 1; local $Data::Dumper::Quotekeys = 0; local $Data::Dumper::Sortkeys = 1;`  This won't get you an output as pretty as `Dump`, but it will be more functional.

Comment: @mpapec please suggest me something on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25621383/handle-similar-check-in-perl