# Handle similar check in perl

Tags: perl

I have multiple params on my page.Now i want to validate all params from a array of hash,that whether it contains similar data as in the params that i have.There will be 2 conditions either the array of has have the value ,if it has value it must match from the param value,if the value value is blank then by default it will return true value.

**Param**

```
$validate_param->{email}        = $saved_hash->{param}->{email};
$validate_param->{country_name} = $saved_hash->{param}->{country};
$validate_param->{city_name}    = $saved_hash->{param}->{city_name};
$validate_param->{ht_name}      = $saved_hash->{output}->{req}->{$args->{keynode}}->{Name};
$validate_param->{ht_rm}        = $saved_hash->{param}->{room};
$validate_param->{ht_rt}        = $saved_hash->{output}->{rating};
```

**Array**

```
[{
  'country_name' => 'AF|IN|AZ',
  'ht_rm'        => '1|2|3',
  'ht_rt'        => '2',
  'city_name'    => 'Kabul|Agra',
  'ht_name'      => 'Safi Landmark Hotel and Suites|SAFI LANDMARK HOTEL SUITES',
  'email'        => 'test@test.com|test2@test.com'
 }]
```

Please help me how can we match the data in an optimized way without repetition of code.
Param will have single value but in the aaray we have multiple values that will be pipe seprated.So i have to check whether array contains the param value or not

**sample data**

```
$validate_param->{email} ="test2@test.com"; 
$validate_param->{country_name}="AF";
$validate_param->{city_name} ="Kabul"; 
$validate_param->{ht_name} ="Safi Landmark Hotel and Suites"; 
$validate_param->{ht_rm} ="2";
$validate_param->{ht_rt} ="3"
```

;

Comment: Add to the question examples of $validate_param, $saved_hash and other input data, and how result should look like.

Comment: @mpapec updated my question please check if the any of the data matches from the validate_param and the array then it will return true else it will return false

Comment: @mpapec have u got the issue for what i am looking for ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simplest to transform the list of valid values from a pipe-separated list to an array. Then the `any` function from the [`List::Util`](https://metacpan.org/module/List::Util) module will make the check very straightforward.

It's not clear from your question what the array of valid values looks like. You say it is an array of hashes, but it contains only a single hash in your example. Is it always like that? I have hard-coded `$validate_rules[0]` in this solution so it will always use the first hash in the array to check the parameters. That may need to be changed.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use List::Util 'any';

my @validate_rules = (
  {
    country_name => 'AF|IN|AZ',
    ht_rm        => '1|2|3',
    ht_rt        => '2',
    city_name    => 'Kabul|Agra',
    ht_name      => 'Safi Landmark Hotel and Suites|SAFI LANDMARK HOTEL SUITES',
    email        => 'test@test.com|test2@test.com'
  }
);

my $validate_param = {
  email        => 'test2@test.com', 
  country_name => 'AF',
  city_name    => 'Kabul', 
  ht_name      => 'Safi Landmark Hotel and Suites', 
  ht_rm        => '2',
  ht_rt        => '3',
};

# Change each string of valid values to an array
for my $entry ( @validate_rules ) {
   $_ = [ split /\|/ ] for values %$entry;
}

while ( my ($key, $val) = each %$validate_param ) {
  my $valid = any { $_ eq $val } @{ $validate_rules[0]{$key} };
  printf qq{Key "%s" %s\n}, $key, $valid ? 'ok' : 'invalid';
}
```

**output**

```
Key "city_name" ok
Key "ht_name" ok
Key "ht_rm" ok
Key "country_name" ok
Key "email" ok
Key "ht_rt" invalid
```

Tool completed successfully

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need verification function; `validate()` should return true when it pass all rules,

```
sub validate {
  my ($input, $rules) = @_;

  for my $key (keys %$rules) {

    $input->{$key} =~ /$rules->{$key}/ or return;
  }
  return 1;
}

my $rules = [{
  'country_name' => qr'^(AF|IN|AZ)\z',
  'ht_rm'        => qr'^[123]\z',
  'ht_rt'        => qr'^2\z',
  'city_name'    => qr'^(Kabul|Agra)\z',
  'ht_name'      => qr'^(Safi Landmark Hotel and Suites|SAFI LANDMARK HOTEL SUITES)\z',
  'email'        => qr'^(test\@test\.com|test2\@test\.com)\z',
}];
for my $rule (@$rules) {
  print validate($validate_param, $rule) ? "ok\n" : "not ok\n";
}
```

Here, each entry in `$rules` is a regular expression, and we simply run Perl's normal regex matching on the values you pass in. If a regex matches, the field is valid.  Of course, care must be taken to create rules which really only match what they are supposed to.

Comment: it's very complicated for me please explain a bit i am not able to understand this

Comment: $rules will be array of multiple hashes how then we will handle

Comment: @Gaurav check update. No, it will not be true. https://eval.in/187186 (https://eval.in/187187 in case it should be)